# Getting "duplicate class" error in IntelliJ Idea Community edition, preventing complete compilation of workspace

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, code-duplication

I am trying to compile my entire workspace with about 200 modules in it. Using javac compiler with extra arguments `-Xmaxerrs 1000 -Xmaxwarns 1000`
However, the compilation is getting stopped due to the error of duplicate classes being found.
[Duplicate Class error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evPDg.png)

Duplicate classes do exist in my workspace, however, I am not sure which one of them I can delete without leading to consequent dependency issues. Hence I want duplicate classes to existing as it is, but I want IntelliJ to stop giving me this error. Can somebody please help me out and show me how to either suppress/ignore this error so that the compilation does not stop? Thanks in advance

I tried `@SuppressWarnings('Duplicates')` on top of the duplicate classes but that did not stop the IntelliJ compiler from giving me the same error.
I also tried checking all possible Editor -> Inspections but there is no option for ignoring duplicate classes.
I also increased the shared heap memory for the compiler to 4096 MB.
Tried rebuilding the entire workspace, did not help.
Increased javac compiler inbuilt error limit from 100 to 1000000

(Edit 1) Note: Just to be clear, duplicate classes are NOT in the same package, but in different packages across different modules

(Edit 2) [Duplicate class example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fReBK.png) [Class on left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXNSL.png) [Class on right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbAkK.png)

Comment: this is not possible, you can't have duplicate classes in the same package. even if it was possible to compile it, how would the runtime know which class to load?

Comment: @Pavel its not in the same package... they are in different packages in different modules

Comment: please provide more source code to check the duplication warning

Comment: @devwebcl pls check edit. Tell me if you require anything else

Comment: according the screenshots you shared, both classes are in the same package `com.iflex.fcr.db.procedure.wrapper.impl`. That just won't work .

Comment: @Pavel I see. So even if they are in different modules, that does not make any difference?

Comment: sure, it doesn't matter where are the modules (source code), the classes are loaded with the same classloader.